# I get sqldriver error in QtCreator

Tags: qt

I try to write a program in Qt Creator using db library. When i run my application in Qt Creator, i get that error:  "QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE"
The qsqlodbc.dll and qsqlodbcd.dll files exist in the plugins/sqldrivers folder of the Qt 5.1.0 installation.
Why can not it find the driver altough it exits in the default installation?

Thanks

Comment: Are you launching your program in debug mode? If you are using Windows, try copying the sqldrivers folder to the same folder as your executable.

Comment: i had tried it but it did not solved...

Comment: Even if you launch your .exe manually?